# When deleting item in Combobox the secong one pop-up MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, combobox

I have combo box and delete button. I want to make next combo box item pop-up when delete button pressed and when last item deleted clean combo box selected item.

I tried several methods with indexes but even one wont help me.

there is my code:

```
if(IDYES == MessageBox(L"Delete save?",L"Delete", MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION)){
            CString pFileName = L"Save\\"+str+".dat";
            CFile::Remove(pFileName);
            CComboBox* pComboBox = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO_SAVE);
            pComboBox->ResetContent();
        }
```

How I can to make next combo box item pop-up when delete button pressed and when last item deleted clean combo box selected item?

Comment: please clarify what you need by "popup". Based on your code you are deleting the file and resetting the whole content of combobox (removing all strings from combobox). What do you expect your program to do?

Comment: as i say i want that action: when selected item deletes the selection must set to another item (to prevent manually select another item from combobox) and if last item deleted combobox cleared... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
void CL2HamsterDlg::OnBnClickedButtonDelete(){
    if(Validate()){
        if(IDYES == MessageBox(L"Delete save?",L"Delete", MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION)){
            CString pFileName = L"Save\\"+str+".dat";
            CFile::Remove(pFileName);
            CComboBox* pComboBox = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO_SAVE);
            lookforfile();
            int nIndex = pComboBox->GetCurSel();
            if (nIndex == CB_ERR)
                pComboBox->SetCurSel(0);
            else{
                pComboBox->SetEditSel(0, -1);
                pComboBox->Clear();
            }
        }
        LoadSave(false);
    }else
        AfxMessageBox(L"Please select or write correct name!");
}
```

the function look for file refreshes index

```
void CL2HamsterDlg::lookforfile()
{
    Value.GetWindowText(str);
    CComboBox* pComboBox = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO_SAVE);
    pComboBox->ResetContent();
    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH,curWorkingDir);
    _tcscat_s(curWorkingDir, MAX_PATH, _T("\\Save\\*.dat"));
    BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile(curWorkingDir);
    while (bWorking){   
        bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();
        if (!finder.IsDots())
            pComboBox->AddString(finder.GetFileTitle());
    }
    GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO_SAVE)->SetWindowText(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

so, in this case you do not need to use ResetContent(). Provided you already know the currently selected Item in the combobox (I think somewhere along the track you would have used the line `int iSel = pComboBox->GetCurSel();`) you could use this code IN PLACE OF YOUR `pComboBox->ResetContent();`:

```
pComboBox->DeleteString(iSel);
if(iSel < pComboBox->GetCount())
  pComboBox->SetCurSel(iSel);
else if(iSel > 0)
  pComboBox->SetCurSel(iSel-1);
```

However, I think this will not be necessary. I think the item will move by itself. So, forget about the code above, just use this:

```
pComboBox->DeleteString(pComboBox->GetCurSel())
```